# Angular-Translate: Translation does not show up on random browser refreshes

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a separate language json file for each partial/controller. To avoid loading all the json files at once, I have added the `addPart` statement in the controller instead of the module config:

```
$translatePartialLoader.addPart('editName');
```

When I browse to the partial, I see that the json file is requested from the server only when needed. But when I keep refreshing the partial by clicking the function key <kbd>F5</kbd>, at random times, the json file is not requested from the server and the text displayed on the view is not translated. Not sure what I can do to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
angular.module('pp')
    .controller('informationList', [
        '$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate',
            function($scope, $rootScope, $location, $translatePartialLoader, $translate) {
                $translatePartialLoader.addPart('informationList');
                $translate.refresh();
            }
    ]);
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: some browsers when the redirect is to frequent catch some content like json, or images in this case watching for the file to download is not enough you need to provide a failsafe in case the file is already there when the page loads

Answer (score 1):

Your issue sounds similar to mine.

This (called from app config) works:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function ($translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {
  $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
    'urlTemplate': '{part}-{lang}.json'
  });
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('EN');

  $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('headline');
  $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('languages');
});
```

This (called from controller) does not:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($scope, $translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
  $translatePartialLoader.addPart('headline');
  $translatePartialLoader.addPart('languages');
  $translate.refresh();
}]);
```

Here is a plunker to demonstrate the problem.
http://plnkr.co/edit/sZC2XST8BMZcMCYbgtxt?p=preview

Comment: can you check my answer right above? Maybe that helps you already.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just add a

```
$translateProvider.use('EN');
```

to the config - section just right below the "preferredLanguage('EN');" - line?

This should solve your problem.

It is in in fact currently needed to define that additional line - even though it might sound a bit like "duplication" :-).